# SVG pattern contains whitespace between repetitions in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I'm using an inline svg that fills an area with a lined pattern. The svg displays correctly Chrome and Safari but on Firefox there are gaps in between the vertical repetitions of the pattern as shown below:

[image]

```
<svg version="1.1" id="clouds" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 744.9 203" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet ">
    <pattern  x="66.95" y="122" width="24" height="24" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="line-fill" viewBox="0 -24 24 24" overflow="visible">
        <polygon fill="none" points="0,0 24,0 24,-24 0,-24"/>
        <g>
            <polygon fill="#D83D96" points="4.4,-9.5 0,-5.1 0,-6.9 9.5,-16.4 9.5,-16.4 17.1,-24 18.9,-24 16.7,-21.5 16.7,-21.5"/>
            <polygon fill="#D83D96" points="4.4,-21.5 0,-17.1 0,-18.9 5.1,-24 6.9,-24"/>
            <polygon fill="#D83D96" points="24,-6.9 24,-5.1 18.9,0 17.1,0 21.8,-4.4"/>
            <polygon fill="#D83D96" points="24,-18.9 24,-17.1 16.7,-9.5 16.7,-9.5 6.9,0 5.1,0 9.5,-4.4 9.5,-4.4 21.8,-16.4"/>
        </g>
    </pattern>
    <g fill="url(#line-fill)">
        <circle cx="12.5" cy="22.5" r="12.5"/>
        <path d="M180.5,54.5c-10.1,0-19.6,2.3-28.1,6.5c6.3-6.5,10.1-15.3,10.1-25c0-19.9-16.1-36-36-36
            c-18.9,0-34.4,14.6-35.9,33.1c-4.2-4.1-9.9-6.6-16.2-6.6C61.5,26.5,51,37,51,49.9c0,12.7,10.1,23,22.6,23.4
            C64.7,79.9,59,90.5,59,102.5c0,20.2,16.3,36.5,36.5,36.5c8.4,0,16.1-2.8,22.3-7.6c6,29.2,31.8,51.1,62.7,51.1c35.3,0,64-28.7,64-64
            C244.5,83.2,215.8,54.5,180.5,54.5z M126.8,83.7c-6.4-10.6-18-17.7-31.3-17.7c-1.5,0-2.9,0.1-4.4,0.3c2.7-2.7,4.7-6.1,5.8-9.8
            c6.5,9.4,17.3,15.6,29.6,15.6c4.4,0,8.7-0.8,12.6-2.3C134.3,73.8,130.2,78.5,126.8,83.7z"/>
        <path d="M702.8,87.9v-0.3h0c-0.2-18.3-15-33.1-33.4-33.1S636.2,69.3,636,87.6h-2.2
            c1.4-3.9,2.1-8.2,2.1-12.6c0-21-17-38-38-38c-16.7,0-30.8,10.7-35.9,25.7c-4.2-17.5-20.4-30.6-39.8-30.6c-18.4,0-33.9,11.7-39,27.8
            V41h0c0-0.3,0-0.7,0-1c0-15.1-12.3-27.4-27.4-27.4c-15.1,0-27.4,12.3-27.4,27.4c0,0.3,0,0.7,0,1h-3.9
            c-1.4-12.1-11.7-21.5-24.2-21.5c-12.5,0-22.8,9.4-24.2,21.5H376v81.3h107.3v-0.1h219.5V87.9C702.8,87.9,702.8,87.9,702.8,87.9
            C702.8,87.9,702.8,87.9,702.8,87.9z M562.1,87.6h-2.6c0.6-1.2,1.1-2.5,1.5-3.8C561.4,85.1,561.7,86.4,562.1,87.6z M483.3,83.1
            c0.5,1.5,1.1,3,1.8,4.5h-1.8V83.1z"/>
        <circle cx="642" cy="172.6" r="30.4"/>
        <circle cx="732.6" cy="173.6" r="12.2"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is a fiddle to fiddle with: http://jsfiddle.net/Qs3Y9/

It seems to possibly be a rounding issue since the gaps disappear and reappear as the bounding box is resized but I am fairly new to svg patterns so I'm at a loss as to where to even start looking for the solution.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, perhaps the same as this one: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843057 (a thin hairline is visible on firefox on linux too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens on Webkit and other browsers also.  It is just not as obvious.  It is just to do with antialiasing where the pattern squares touch.  You can mitigate it by not having your hatch lines terminate exactly at the pattern boundary.  Have them extend past it a bit.  The extensions won't be drawn but it will mean the that antialiasing will be invisible (or almost invisible).

```
<pattern  x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="line-fill" viewBox="0 0 24 24" overflow="visible" stroke="#D83D96" stroke-width="1.5">
   <line x1="-2" y1="8" x2="8" y2="-2"/>
   <line x1="-2" y1="20" x2="20" y2="-2"/>
   <line x1="4" y1="26" x2="26" y2="4"/>
   <line x1="16" y1="26" x2="26" y2="16"/>
</pattern>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qs3Y9/2/